# Concatenating two strings not working

Tags: python, python-3.x, text

I have the following code:

```
name=input("What do you want to call your file?")
print(name)
name=name+".txt"
print(name)
```

When I run it, I get:

```
<whatever was input>
.txt
```

I want to get:

```
<whatever was input>
<whatever was input>.txt
```

I have tried doing:

```
input("What do you want to call your file?")+".txt"
```

And:

```
input("What do you want to call your file?")
+=".txt"
```

but no luck.

What is curious is that when I run it in the shell, it works l, and also that it works in python 3.1 but not 3.4.

Comment: Cannot reproduce…

Comment: it works as expected

Comment: If your using shell, it worked for me there to. In command prompt(when I just double clicked the program) I got the problem. Have added that to my question.

Comment: Tried it on another computer, and no problem. Wondering what is going on. The one it worked on is Windows 7 Proffesional, 32-bit, will post later on the one it raised an error.

Answer (score 3):

Remove the newline on end:

```
name = input("Q?").rstrip('\n') + "txt"
```

Or do it like so:

```
# thanks to Delirious Lettuce: f'{input("Filename?").rstrip('\n')}.txt'.replace("\n","") 
name = f'{input("Filename?")}.txt'.replace("\n","")
print(name)
```

What stumps though is, that the input() normally removes the return that closes its input.

I wonder why you get one ... for me `name = f'{input("Filename?")}.txt'` works and `name` comes out as `'tata.txt'` if I input 'tata' and hit return.

Comment: @DeliriousLettuce thanks for the catch - seems I used rstrip() without the\n when testing it in pyfiddle.io

Comment: As added to my question, it works in shell. Is it possible that it doesn't remove the \n in command prompt?

Comment: using code `filename=exec("input('Filename?')+'.txt'")` , I get error: `file=open(filename, "w")`
`TypeError: invalid file: None`

Comment: `rstrip` or `replace` not working, same problem as in the question. still working in shell.

Comment: @ArtemisFowl you are misusing exec. Python functions always return `None` if they do not return something implicitly. Exec does not return anything. So it returns None. Read [exec](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#exec) - the first paragraf, carefully.

Comment: would exec("filename=input('Filename?')+'.txt'") work @PatrickArtner

Comment: @ArtemisFowl exec has no return - you would have to put all stuff inside it. what are you really trying to accomplish here? Read here: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem